# AJAX function to webmethod doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

I have a 2 ajax functions on my page.  One that works when a link inside a grid is clicked and one when a button is clicked.  The one from the grid works perfectly.  However, the function from the click of a button produces an error every time.

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong here.  I would appreciate any help. Here is the one that fails:

```
    function createSource() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/createSource",
            data: '{"schoolID":"' + $('#ddSchools').val() + '","vendor":"' + $('#txtVendor').val() + '","tSource":"' +  $('#txtTSource').val()+ '"}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
```

The Webmethod will have more code to it but i cant seem to hit it anyway.  Here is the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string createSource(int schoolId, string vendor, string tSource)
{
    try
    {
        string status = "This is a test string!";

        return status;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not create source code!");
    }
}
```

Also how can i go about getting the exact error that is causing this function to fail?

Thank you in advance for any help!!

---

ok so i figured where the problem is but i still do not have a solution.  There actually wasn't anything wrong with the code.  I plugged the code in at document.ready and it fired correctly.  However, it will not fire correctly whenever the button is clicked.  The button is nothing special either.  It is a simple input button.

```
<input id="cmdSubmit_Create" value="Submit" type="submit" />
```

any ideas?

For reference i will put the code that works on the document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/createSource",
            data: '{"schoolId":"2236","vendor":"test","tsource":"test1234"}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("status: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("status: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
});

[WebMethod]
public static string helloWorld(string schoolId, string vendor,string tsource)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Hello World! " + schoolId + '-' + vendor + '-' + tsource);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not create source code!");
    }
}
```

If i try to call the same webmethod on the click of cmdSubmit_Create it doesnt work:

```
       $('#cmdSubmit_Create').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/helloWorld",
            data: '{"schoolId":"2236","vendor":"test","tsource":"test1234"}',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('error' + error)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code

```
$('#cmdSubmit_Create').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.aspx/helloWorld",
        data: '{"schoolId":"2236","vendor":"test","tsource":"test1234"}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('error' + error)
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-call-csharp-function-in-ajax.html

Comment: HA! Ive been at this for some time and all it took was adding return false.  Thank you for your help as well 3nigma for yours.  It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you service expects a `GET` *UseHttpGet = true* where as you are doing `POST` try instead

```
type: "GET",
```

Comment: My apologies i removed the line of code [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)].  I put it there to try and use a GET but nothing.

Comment: do you see any error in the firebug? does the ajax call is made? do you get a response?

Comment: i do not see an error in firebug.  the thrownerror comes back as undefined.  ive even changed it to not pass anything and simply try and return the string.  Nothing!  For whatever reason, it is not hitting my webmethod.  Returns error immediately

Comment: try without the `contentType` and change your `dataType:json` to `dataType:html` as you are returning a string not json